# Why do I get two "++" characters when I source a bash script with "set -x" versus running with bash?

Tags: bash

I'm having a hard time phrasing what this question is. But the MWE is as follows:

I can make a bash script as follows:

```
echo '
#!/bin/bash
# This is a bash file I will source

set -x
echo "hello world"
{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null

mkdir -p bookkeeping && touch foo
' > mwe_script.sh
```

When I execute this script with: `source mwe_script.sh` I get:

```
++ echo 'hello world'
hello world
```

But when I execute this script with `bash mwe_script.sh` I get:

```
+ echo 'hello world'
hello world
```

Why is the `source` command printing two plus signs (++) whereas the `bash` command is printing one plus sign (+) on the commands being echoed via `set -x`?

Comment: What is your bash version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run

```
bash mwe_script.sh
```

bash run directly commands in mwe_script.sh, so a single `+` is printed.

But when you run

```
source mwe_script.sh
```

bash (current session) runs `source` which then run commands in mwe_script.sh.

As there is one level of indirection, an extra `+` is added.

You can put following script in `mwe_script.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is a bash file I will source
  
next_run=(source $BASH_SOURCE $(($1 + 1)))
echo "Next run is : ${next_run[*]}"
test $1 -lt 5 && ${next_run[@]}
```

and run following in your interactive bash shell:

```
set -x; source mwe_script.sh 1; set +x
```

You'll notice 5 levels of indirections.